# Div Style - Issues with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, border

I have this simple DIV that displays fine in Firefox, Chrome etc, but not IE. I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.example {
        position:absolute; 
        color:black; 
        text-align:left;
        border:2px solid#000;  
        border-radius:15px; 
        -moz-border-radius:15px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="example" style="height:15em;width:10em;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox I get a rounded 2px black border. In IE get nothing. From what I've read, rounded borders isn't supported until IE9, but I would like the 2px black border, even if it's not rounded. Is there anyway to get this to look the same in Firefox, Chrome, IE & Safari ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where is position:relative; . position absolute can be used when you r using position relative;

Comment: What do you mean by "fine"

Comment: Missing Space : Use `border:2px solid #000` instead of `border:2px solid#000`

Comment: In Firefox I get a rounded 2px black border. In IE get nothing.
From what I've read, rounded borders isn't supported until IE9, but I would like the 2px black border, even if it's not rounded.

Comment: @ Pranav Kapoor - Thanks the border is now visible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space in the border style.
Here is a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/uhajiq/4/edit).

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">&nbsp;</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.example {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 10em;
    height: 15em;
}
```

Also, as a side note,

`border-radius` should always be called after `-prefix-border-radius`,

example of order:

```
...
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
...
```